# PHP $_GET A Select Tag

Tags: php

When you $_GET a select tag from a form what is the return value. According to what I'm doing I think it returns an integer (1-# of Options) but I wanted to consult someone more knowledgeable on the subject. Is there a way to get the string of the option selected?

Comment: If you ensure your options have a value attribute you get the value of the attribute

Comment: Adding the code would really help us understand your question and problem

Comment: If a form has a SELECT tag and its selected and you posting form then $_GET will give you array contains SELECT ELEMENT NAME AS ARRAY KEY and SELECT ELEMENT VALUE AS ARRAY VALUE e.g array('select' => 'value')

Answer (score 0):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-form-data-set):

> If the field element is a select element, then for each option element in the select element's list of options whose selectedness is true and that is not disabled, append an entry to the form data set with the name as the name, the value of the option element as the value, and type as the type.

It is the value of the option element(s) that is/are selected. The index will never be sent unless they happen to be the same as the value.

Comment: You are mixing `select` widget with `multi-select`, which creates even more confusion

Comment: @MaxZoom — No I'm not. Select elements work in the same way with or without the `multiple` attribute. The only difference is the number of options that can be selected.

Answer (score 0):

It returns the selected option's value.

```
<select name="someFilter">
  <option value="food">Food</option>
  <option value="drink">Drink</option>
</select>
```

So, in this case `$_GET['someFilter']` will return either `food` or `drink`.

Answer (score 0):

The form will send the **selected option** value(s) or first option if nothing was selected as a selection value.
You can experiment below with selection and submit button to see results:

```js
var form = document.forms['myForm'],
  select = form.querySelector('select'),
  button = form.querySelector('input[type=submit]');

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log('Selected value is ' + this.value)
});

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = new FormData(form);
  var field = 'selection';
  console.log('Form will send ' + data.getAll(field) + ' for ' + field);
  var label = select.querySelector('option[value="' + data.getAll(field) + '"]').innerHTML;
  data.set(field, label)
  console.log('But we can change it to label: ' + data.getAll(field));
});
```

```html
<form name='myForm'>
  <label for='selection'>Select something:</label>
  <select name="selection">
    <option value='0'>---</option>
    <option value='1'>First</option>
    <option value='2'>Second</option>
    <option value='3'>Third</option>
  </select>
  <br/><br/>
  <input type='submit' value="submit" />
</form>
```